# How to update "prevState" in react.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have got a list of array of objects. I want to update the state. When I click on the 1st item of the array, it's giving `isTrue: false`, when I click on the second array of items, `isTrue` is given as `true`. I want to get 1st item `isTrue:true`, when I click on the second array of items that give `isTrue: true`.
How can I do this?

[Here is the link](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-cannon-7ffmq)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Child from "./child";
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      { id: "2", name: "johan", org: "ORg" },
      { id: "1", name: "doe", org: "ORg" }
    ]
  };
  handleClick = e => {
    let newData = this.state.data.map(obj => {
      if (obj.id === e.target.id) {
        return { ...obj, isTrue: !obj.isTrue };
      } else {
        return { ...obj, isTrue: false };
      }
    });

    this.setState({ data: newData });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(item => (
          <Child data={item} key={item.id} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
        ))}
        {/* <Child data={this.state.data} handleClick={this.handleClick} /> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this help ?https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: I try to solve many ways, but can not find the solution. did you understand I want to get ?

Comment: Can you understand your problem by just reading your question statement?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by clicking on list items?

Comment: when I click on second items , prevstate will be changed, for example: items:true , items:true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more than one boolean in state to manage all of them. Update your data to be:

```
data: [
  { id: "name", name: "ss", org: "s", isTrue: true },
  { id: "nams", name: "ss", org: "s", isTrue: true }
]
```

Then add a name or id to your `li`s

```js
<li id={item.id} onClick={this.handleClick}>{item.name}</li>
```

Then update your change handler to update the correct data object

```js
handleClick = (e) => {
  // Map over old data and return new objects so we dont mutate state
  let newData = this.state.data.map(obj => {
    // If the ID matches then update the value
    if (obj.id == e.target.id) {
      return {...obj, isTrue: !obj.isTrue}
    }

     // else return the same object
     return obj;
  });

  // Update the state with the new object
  this.setState({ data: newData });
};
```

Comment: Because this setState depends on the previous state, you should put it inside a call back https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: @CameronDowner In this case it doesn't matter because we are creating the new state object synchronously, and then setting it asynchronously, so any async conflict is avoided. If we had done the mapping inside `setState` then yes it should be done with a functional update.

Comment: To illustrate: `this.setState({ data: this.state.map(...)})`. The mapping here is actually executed asynchronously, so the data may be stale and we should use a functional update. But doing `let data = this.state.map(...); this.setState({ data: data });` The mapping is done synchronously as soon as the click handler is called, so the data will be correct.

Comment: That's not to say this is always a safe practice, it depends on the specific use-case. If this handler would have been called more than once before the next re-render say from inside a loop, then it would be susceptible to the stale data problem. But for a simple handler like this that will only be triggered once per render cycle, its safe.

Comment: Possibly I am missing something, my understanding is how ReactJS *could* batch the state updates could make the reference to `this.state` make the state update 'incorrect'. In practise, you may not see it on your device but could cause bugs hard to detect?